# Sanitising ASP.NET input (allowing angle brackets)

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have read about customising input validation for ASP.NET requests to avoid the dreaded "a potentially dangerous value was detected". I'm using the following code to allow angled brackets to pass validation.

```
public class RequestValidator : System.Web.Util.RequestValidator {
    protected override bool IsValidRequestString(HttpContext context, string value, RequestValidationSource requestValidationSource, string collectionKey, out int validationFailureIndex) {
        validationFailureIndex = 0;

        switch (requestValidationSource) {
            case RequestValidationSource.Form:
                if (control is CustomTextBox) { // How can I get the control?
                    // allow angle brackets to pass validation
                    value = value.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;");
                }
                break;
        }

        return base.IsValidRequestString(context, value, requestValidationSource, collectionKey, out validationFailureIndex);
    }
}
```

Now that I'm allowing these potentially dangerous values through the validation filter I'd like to be *sure* that they're being properly handled. This is a Web Forms environment so I thought I'd create a `CustomTextBox` control, override the `Text` property and `HtmlEncode` the string.

As you can see from the comment in the code above, I'd like to restrict my `RequestValidator` so that it only allows 'dangerous' values to pass validation if I can be sure they're going to be handled by my `CustomTextBox`. How can I get a reference to the `Control` when all we have to go on is the `value` and the `collectionKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation of the Form Keys happen even before the Page `PreInit` event. There are no controls created at that time.

I think your best chance would be holding to a collection of UniqueIDs of all `CustomTextBox` instances that exists on the page currently. Having that collection, you could check if the form key being validated exists on the collection, meaning that it is in fact a `CustomTextBox`.

This collection could be managed inside the `CustomTextBox` control and saved on the Session or Application Cache.

Comment: I thought this might be the case since even `context.Handler` is null. This would probably solve the problem for a single page but I was looking for a more generic solution with a view to incorporating it into a library

Comment: @Red Taz: Do you mean you could have two controls with the same UniqueID on two different pages, where only one of them is a CustomTextBox?

Comment: Theoretically yes. Also, in order to automate the maintenance of the list; every time the application spins up you'd need to enumerate all of the controls on each page and store the results in memory

Comment: I think every instance of the CustomTextBox could register itself on the list in the first time it's created. This list could also be a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` where the keys would be the pages and the value would be the list of UniqueIDs for that page. To help avoiding conflicts you could add another ID layer to the CustomTextBox control, a Panel for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to explicitly set [`ValidateRequestMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.validaterequestmode.aspx) property to `ValidateRequestMode.Disabled` in your custom control constructor and override `Text` property (or whatever property or you are using to store value) getter and there return sanitized value based on your specific scenario.